# get select option value using onchange function in jQuery from multiple dynamic record?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code

```
foreach($test as $val){

<select name="change" onchange="Change()" id="change-<?=$val['id']?>" data-id="<?php echo $val['id'];?>">
     <option value="1">one</option>
     <option value="20">two</option>
     <option value="21">three</option>                
 </select>
}
```

jQuery function

```
 function Change(){
        alert($(this).val());
    }
```

In this code I want different time different value with id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `onchange="Change()"` with `onchange="Change(this)"` In HTML part.

And function should be as below.

```
function Change(el){
    alert("value : "+el.value+" and Id : "+el.id+' and data-id : '+el.getAttribute("data-id"));  
}
```

**Please check Working snippet :**

```js
function Change(el){
  alert("value : "+el.value+" and Id : "+el.id+' and data-id : '+el.getAttribute("data-id"));  
}
```

```html
<select name="change" onchange="Change(this)" id="change-1" data-id="1">
     <option value="1">one</option>
     <option value="20">two</option>
     <option value="21">three</option>                
 </select>
```

Comment: @Patel sir how to get id ?

Comment: @NeerajPrajapati check updated snippet. You can get id by 'el.id'

Comment: @NeerajPrajapati from el object you can get all the attribute of element. Check it by placing console.log(el); in the Change function.

Comment: sir how to get data-id ?

Comment: Using el.getAttribute("data-id"). Updated the answer as well to show how to get data-id.